# JSQMessagesViewController 7.3.4 + Firebase (3.7.1) observeMessages cannot access FIRDataSnapshot

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am just trying to observe JSQMessages with the latest versions and Swift 3.0 and the following code is what reported in any other question about this but for some reason the dictionary contained in FIRDataSnapshot is returning compilation error "Type 'Any' has no subscript members.

[image]

Did anyone encounter the same problem and overcome it? Thanks!

Comment: I have found a solution, not sure it is the best but it works:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer sticking to the Firebase data types for as long as possible. In that case you get the values with:

```
snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "text").value as! String
```

So:

```
private func observeMessages() {
    let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimited(toLast: 25)

    messagesQuery.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
        let id = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String
        let text = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "text").value as! String
        self.addMessage(id: id, text: text)
        self.finishReceivingMessage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, not sure it is the best way, basically I forced casting to NSDictionary:

```
private func observeMessages() {
        let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimited(toLast: 25)

        messagesQuery.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in

            let id = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["name"] as! String
            let text = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["text"] as! String
            //let photoUrl = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["photoUrl"] as! String

            self.addMessage(id: id, text: text)
            self.finishReceivingMessage()
        }
    }
```